# Using the SoundCloud HTML5 widget in a webView changes it's appearance to look like a 'web app'

Tags: soundcloud

It's very annoying that SoundCloud has such a nice HTML5 player which works perfectly in Mobile Safari, yet when you try to use that same iframe in a webView in an app, it transforms itself into this "app-like player interface" totally disregarding all sizes and settings set to the widget.  It tries to pretend to be a webapp (ish), which is not what I asked for in the HTML5 widget.

see in Mobile Safari : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUP6U.jpg

and in a WebView within an iPhone app : https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Qwx.jpg

Is there a query string I can add to the iframe src uri to override this 'over-responsive' design?  Thanks.

Comment: fix for this problem will be deployed in a week or so, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: that's great news. Many thanks and looking forward to it :)

Comment: Hey Kosso. We have just released new version of our HTML5 widget. The problem you described was partially fixed, please tell me if you still get redirected.

Comment: Hi there. Oddly enough, I was just testing this out. Looks good so far! Thanks!

What do you mean by 'partially'?

Comment: We are trying to figure out the best heuristics to determine when it's the best to do the redirection, hopefully current solution will handle most of the cases.